# Network administrator will be able to remotely delete your content

Tags: lumia, email, exchange

I was going to set up my Lumia 1020 to connect to my company's Exchange server, in order to have work e-mail on my phone.

But when I go to do so, I see this message:

> If you're adding a business Exchange account, your network administrator will be able to remotely delete your content and settings from your phone.

I also found this, which is more explicit:

> [Windows® Phone 8 Privacy Statement](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/legal/wp8/windows-phone-privacy-statement#email)
>
> If you set up an Outlook Exchange account on your phone, your network administrator will be able to apply policies to your phone that allow them to require you to use a lock screen password or to disable your SD card. **The administrator may also be able to remotely wipe all the content of your phone (including content that is not company-related).**

Is there a way I can set up the connection to Exchange without allowing this?  For instance, by using IMAP or POP instead?

Comment: Only if they allow pp/IMAP access, or a web frontend. I wouldn't worry about it, the Exchange Administrator was always able to do this with your content.

Comment: @WayneInYak, as I understand it, it's saying he/she can wipe *all* of my content, not just my Exchange content.  If it were just Exchange content, I wouldn't care.

Comment: If a company phone then yes MS has tools to do that. If your own phone  then no or at least I am not aware of this being possible.

Comment: @WayneInYak, read the above.  It doesn't say the administrator can only wipe a company phone.  It says the administrator can wipe any Windows phone with an Outlook Exchange account set up on it, regardless of whom the phone belongs to.

Comment: It doesn't say can, it says may. May as if it is a company phone, probably not if it is a personal phone.

Comment: Doing some searching on the Windows Phone site I only see this language under the section talking about Company Accounts, meaning you are using a company phone accessing apps made by your company and you are using their phone.

Comment: You're not reading enough, @WayneInYak.  "...when you access these apps your company may apply polices to your phone that allow them to require you to use a lock screen password, encrypt the phone’s internal storage, and/or disable your SD card. They may also be able to remotely wipe all the content from your phone (including content that is not company-related) if you enroll your phone with the company. You should carefully consider whether you wish to associate your phone to a company account and be aware of the company’s policies in this regard."

Comment: Oh I read it, what company app are you installing? Hint, Connecting to the exchange server is not installing an app. If you are not installing a company app don;t worry about it. Go under Settings > Company Apps and see what you have installed. Just go into Settings > email + accounts and add a new email account selecting Outlook as the account type.

Comment: @WayneInYak, both of the statements quoted in my question say that merely adding an Exchange account gives the admin access to wipe one's phone.  Clearly you believe this is not the case.  So that we can move forward, please explain why you have more credibility in this area than official statements from Microsoft.

Comment: Did you see what section it was under, i.e. the Company App section of the EULA? Now if you can show me an official MS document making this statement when not referencing the Company Apps then we can go from there, otherwise I think you are reading more into the statement then what is there.. Stop to think, how would only entering your Exchange information allow someone access to the rest of your phone operating system which is tied to your own personal MS account? That would be a security hole so big there would be plenty of blog posts on it.

Comment: **You are not correct.  Company Accounts and Email + Accounts are separate sections.  I cited the Email + Accounts section, which says nothing about company apps.  Nor does the statement on my phone.**

Answer (score 4):

If your email provider offers POP3/SMTP or IMAP/SMTP server endpoints, then you can use them. One of Windows Phone's strengths is the ability for the enterprise to enforce policies. This is the same type of policy that the admin would enforce for laptops and other business assets.

I would ask your IT department what they offer in terms of access.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to speak to your local firendly IT dept - they should have a policy as to when they would do something like wipe your phone. For example, where I work, a device would only be wiped if reported stolen to the IT dept (to protect intelectual property, etc.). It is my understaning that removing the Exchange account removes their ability to do this, too.

They would also be able to advise if they allow IMAP or POP3 access (their security policy may not allow this)